# Fill ListView from a cursor in Android

Tags: android, listview

I've spent a lot of hours searching and reading similar posts, but none of them seem to truly reflect my problem and thus I haven't found anything that works for me.
I've got a database, on which I perform a query, the results of which are stored in a cursor. There's two things to that: 
-the query is performed everytime a certain button is pressed (thus the query is inside the OnClickListener for that Button)
-the query returns two different columns with String values, which must be treated separately (one column stores the names which must be shown in the ListView, the other stores the paths to the image associated toa row)
My problem is, I try to create a String[] which I need to pass to the ArrayAdapter creator for the ListView, but trying to assign it a size of Cursor getCount() crashes my activity. I hope the code will be more of an explanation:

```
OnClickListener searchListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    CardDatabaseOpenHelper helper = new 
    CardDatabaseOpenHelper(DeckEditorScreen1.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    String columns[] = {"name","number","path"};

    Cursor c = db.query("cards", columns, null, null, null, null, "number");
    int count = c.getCount();
    String[] resultNameStrings;
    if (count != 0) resultNameStrings = new String[count];
        else {resultNameStrings = new String[1]; resultNameStrings[1] = "No results";} 
        // This is the offending code
    //Note that if I assign fixed values to resutNameStrings, the code works just
        //fine
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        c.moveToNext();
        int col = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        String s = c.getString(col);
            //Ideally here I would to something like:
            //resultNameStrings[i] = s;
        col = c.getColumnIndex("number");
        int conv = c.getInt(col);
        col = c.getColumnIndex("path");
        String s2 = c.getString(col);
    }
    db.close();

    ArrayAdapter<?> searchResultItemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                                                  (DBScreen.this,
                                                  R.layout.search_result_item,
                                                  resultNameStrings);
    ListView searchResultList = (ListView)
                              DBScreen.this.findViewById(R.id.search_result_list);
    searchResultList.setAdapter(searchResultItemAdapter);
    }
};
Button search_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
search_button.setOnClickListener(searchListener);
```

Comment: What are the values you are getting? for instance, how much is c.getCount()? You are not checking whether c is null, and neither are you checking if c has any result?

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing as @MarvinLabs. Check the count variable. Something along the lines of `Log.i(TAG, "c: "+count);`. You can then run `logcat` and get the logs for your run.

Comment: Actually, I do, I was so desperate I used toasts everywhere to check the correctness of all values. I removed the code for the toasts to make the code clearer. And count was not null.

Comment: @MarvinLabs: Sorry for double comment, but I reread your comment and there's something I don't quite get. Isn't count not being null the same as saying that c holds some results?

Comment: Ok, I added two lines for reacting to the value of of count, but it keeps crashing, no matter wether it's zero or not.

Comment: What do you get as Exception when your application is crashing? At which line does it send you in your code? By the way, the code you added still runs the loop no matter what value of count you are getting, remove it. Follow the answer suggesting to use ContentProviders & CursorAdapter ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDITED*** twice :)

do it in "Android Way" ...

first  use CursorAdapter (fx.: SimpleCursorAdapter with overrided

```
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MobileTraderProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, new String[] { constraint.toString() }, null);
            return cursor;
        }
```

then

```
customAdapter.getFilter().filter(filterText) 
// it will call runQueryOnBackgroundThread
```

second use ContentProvider(it will manage curosors for you ... it will even requery if data changed)

EDIT:

first really use my advice

second before

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        c.moveToNext();
//...
```

add c.moveToFirst();

thrid:  use

```
if(c.moveToNext()) 
{ 
  int col = c.getColumnIndex("name"); 
//..... rest goes here
}
```

SECOND EDIT:

MyProvider.java

```
public class MyProvider extends ContentProvider {

    static final String LTAG = "MyAppName";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://my.app.Content");


    static final int CARDS = 1;
    static final int CARD = 2;
    public static final String CARDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/Cards";
    public static final String CARD_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/Cards";
    static final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    static final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    static {
        //static "Constructor"
        matcher.addURI(Constants.AUTHORITY, "Cards", LISTS);
        matcher.addURI(Constants.AUTHORITY, "Cards/*", LIST);
        map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "ROWID AS _id");
        map.put(Tables.Cards.C_NAME, Tables.Cards.C_NAME);
        map.put(Tables.Cards.C_NUMBER, Tables.Cards.C_NUMBER);
        map.put(Tables.Cards.C_PATH, Tables.Cards.C_PATH);
    }

    private CardDatabaseOpenHelper mDB;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        try {
            mDB = new CardDatabaseOpenHelper(getContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LTAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        String table = null;
        switch (matcher.match(uri)) {
            case CARD:
                //overriding selection and selectionArgs
                selection = "ROWID=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { uri.getPathSegments().get(1) };
                table = uri.getPathSegments().get(0);
                break;
            case CARDS: 
                //this version will delete all rows if you dont provide selection and selectionargs
                table = uri.getPathSegments().get(0);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }
        int ret = mDB.getWritableDatabase().delete(table, selection, selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, table), null);
        return ret;     
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (matcher.match(uri)) {
            case CARDS:
                return CARDS_MIME_TYPE;
            case CARD:
                return CARD_MIME_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }
    }

    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        String table, rowid;
        switch (matcher.match(uri)) {
            case CARD:
                //overriding selection and selectionArgs
                selection = "ROWID=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { uri.getPathSegments().get(1) };
                table = uri.getPathSegments().get(0);
                break;
            case CARDS: 
                //this version will update all rows if you dont provide selection and selectionargs
                table = uri.getPathSegments().get(0);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }
        int ret = mDB.getWritableDatabase().update(table, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, table), null);
        return ret;
    }

    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        String table = null;
        switch (matcher.match(uri)) {
            case CARDS:
                table = uri.getPathSegments().get(0);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }
        mDB.getWritableDatabase().insert(table, null, values);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, table), null);
        return null;
    }

    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        switch (matcher.match(uri)) {
            case CARDS:
                builder.setTables(uri.getPathSegments().get(0));
                break;
            case CARD:
                builder.setTables(uri.getPathSegments().get(0));
                selection = "ROWID=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { uri.getPathSegments().get(1) };  
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }
        builder.setProjectionMap(map);
        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDB.getReadableDatabase(), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;      
    }       
}
```

CardCursorAdapter.java

```
class CardCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

@Override
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
    //search in cards.name
    String selection = Tables.Cards.C_NAME + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"%" + constraint.toString() + "%"};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, Tables.Cards.Name), 
        getCursor().getColumnNames(), selection, selectionArgs, null);
    return cursor;
}
}
```

Tables.java

```
public static class Tables {
    //table definition
    public static interface Cards {
        public static final String NAME = "cards";
        public static final String C_NAME = "name";
        public static final String C_NUMBER = "number";
        public static final String C_PATH = "path";
    }
    //other tables go here
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
</manifest> 
        </application>
            <!-- ....... other stuff    ....... -->
            <provider android:name="MyProvider" android:authorities="my.app.Content" />
        </application>
</manifest>
```

then in activity

```
onCreate(...){

    listView.setAdapter(new CardCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, 
        managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, Tables.Cards.NAME),
            new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, Tables.Cards.C_NAME, Tables.Cards.C_NUMBER, Tables.Cards.C_PATH },
            null,null, number), 
        new String[] { Tables.Cards.C_NAME, Tables.Cards.C_NUMBER, Tables.Cards.C_PATH  }, 
        new int[] { R.id.tName, R.id.tNumber, R.id.tPath }));
}


OnClickListener searchListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DeckEditorScreen1.this.listView.getAdapter().getFilter().filter("text for search in name column of card table set me to empty for all rows");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your advice looks good, gonna try now! The only thing is I'm pretty new to Android, could you explain the first part a little bit more? For example, what value should "constraint" have? By CONTENT_URI, do you mean my database? What should filtertext be? I can see the advantges of running the query in a background thread, but in a situation where the user can't do anything before the query is resolved, wouldn't it be better to show a progress bar or something like that?

Comment: @Axagthoth i'm pretty new to android to (month or so), but i read a lot and watch google i/o 2010 read more, then read more .... ***see my second edit for full example***

Comment: For another more androidy (read: programmatic) way of creating that content URI, you can use a URIBuilder, set the scheme to "content", and the other values as appropriate for the content provider URI. Here's the Android doc on ContentProviders, which should be helpful:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: WOW, thanks Selvin, perhaps I'm gonna use some of that code. Actually, I solved my problem but couldn't post the answer because I'm a newb and I must wait 24 hours XD. I'm used to programming in C++, and there are some things java just won't swallow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've done some testing and I think I know what was the problem. Java allows constructs like:

```
String[] whatever; 
if (something) whatever = new String[avalue];
else whatever = new String[anothervalue];
```

The crash occurs if you don't assign a concrete value to each and every field whatever[i]. The rest of the code is now just fine, though I've added Selvin's correction

```
if (c.moveToNext) ...
```

c.moveToFirst() is not correctly used in my case, as the for iterates count times. If you perform a moveToFirst first, you're always missing the first element pointed by the cursor.

Comment: `ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();c.moveToFirst(); do{ array.add(c.getString(col)); } while(c.moveToNext());String[] resultNameStrings = array.toArray(new String[array.size()]);`

Comment: but why, oh why for the Flying Spaghetti Monster's sake you didn't use SimpleCursorAdapter... u don't need to copy data from cursor to array to show data

Comment: Right! As I said I'm pretty new to Android and I have to get used to (and know) all the utilities and functonalities out there. Anyways, thanks for the new code snippet.