# Change an item in a list

Tags: android-listview, baseadapter, listviewitem

How we can modify an item in a list. I have the list populated with data, I want to click on an item, I change the item in another activity and then when I press a button called save I can register the new entry for the item. I know that I have to use :

```
                   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){                      
                   @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id),
```

for doing this. Can anyone give me an idea ? Thanks ! I suppose that I have to play with the item position. I hope that you can give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be storing the data in a Content Provider and using a Cursor Loader to populate the data in the list view. You may want to check out this link:

[Fill ListView from a cursor in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652091/fill-listview-from-a-cursor-in-android)

The alternative would be to startActivityForResult to the edit activity and pass the updated version back to the list activity. The onActivityResult would then alter the listview directly.  I wouldn't recommend this approach, but if you are in a real time crunch, it's a lot less code.  Content providers take some time to implement.

Comment: If you use a content provider, you don't have to pass it back, you just have to notify the the data has changed.  Any cursor loaders that are listening to that content uri will automatically refresh!  If you use the second method you would use the setResult(data) method.